# Android SQLite reads data before update statement commited

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating a simple android app that works with sqlite. In one activity it shows data to the user and in another one user can manipulates data.
Now, the problem is that when user changes data in second activity and press back button,  `onResume()` method will be called and read data from database, but before update is completed and therefore shows the wrong data (the data before changing).
If user restarts the program it will show right data. I think maybe it has synchronization problems.

Update statement executes in second activity's `onDestroy()` method and instantly select statement executes in `onResume()` in first activity.

What can i do to fix this problem and always see right data in first activity?
I can attach code if it's necessary.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fail design flaw.  You save data preferably when the user changes it.  In the lifecycle in onPause.  onDestroy() is for cleanup of tasks and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement a callback to the first activity that is called when the data loading is changed. Inside the callback method the activity would update the shown data. Easy going.

Please note, if you don't know how to do that: I won't provide code samples. That's not the job of the Stack Overflow community. Just google it and try it out.

Comment: thank for your help it works but i was searching for a way to lock the data base so when updating didn't commited select statement will wait.

Answer (score 0):

look at this from doc:

> Activity A starts Acivity B:
>
> ```
> Activity A's onPause() method executes.
> Activity B's onCreate(), onStart(), and onResume() methods execute in sequence. (Activity B now has user focus.)
> ```
>
> Then, if Activity A is no longer visible on screen, its onStop()
>   method executes. This predictable sequence of lifecycle callbacks
>   allows you to manage the transition of information from one activity
>   to another. For example, if you must write to a database when the
>   first activity stops so that the following activity can read it, then
>   you should write to the database during onPause() instead of during
>   onStop().

so Activity A `onDestroy` still has not been called so you miss the correct data, what should you do? do update in `onPause()` or set listener for a `button` and do updates in that listener.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html